# XAML cannot find reference in local namespace

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

I created a new Metro Split App in C++ using VS2012 on Win8 (both RC). Everything compiled and worked out of the box. I then changed went through and changed the generated namespaces to my own. After some trials and tribulations, I got everything to compile with no warnings, errors, nor messages. The app (as it comes in the project template) runs fine.

However, if I try to edit either of the generated xaml files (ItemsPage.xaml or SplitPage.xaml) I get a "Markup error" on the first line:

The name "LayoutAwarePage" does not exist in the namespace "using:A.B.Product.Client.Common".

The definition of the class is:

```
namespace A{ namespace B { namespace Product { namespace Client { namespace Common
```

The code compiles fine, and runs fine. This only happens in design mode.

UPDATE: I added a new xaml file and (after fixing up the namespaces again) everything worked.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: What is the name of the .winmd file produced by your project?  The name of the .winmd file must be a prefix of the namespace name.  So, for that namespace, the .winmd must be named A.winmd, A.B.winmd, A.B.Product.winmd, A.B.Product.Client.winmd, or A.B.Product.Client.Common.winmd.  This requirement is imposed by the runtime for public types in components (dlls).  However, the designer ends up loading your exe as a dll, so if you want to use the designer, your classes must match the same naming requirements in application projects as well.

Comment: [If that doesn't help, please let me know and I can help investigate.]

Comment: Fantastic! The WinMD file was simply Client.winmd. I unloaded the project, changed the root namespace to be A.B.Product.Client, then reloaded and rebuilt the project. The WinMD file is now called A.B.Product.Client and the XAML loads correctly. That's definitely the answer. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the WinMD file produced by your project must be some prefix of the namespaces in which the public WinRT types are defined.  Given that your type is in the `A.B.Product.Client.Common` namespace , the WinMD file must have one of the following names:

```
A.winmd
A.B.winmd
A.B.Product.winmd
A.B.Product.Client.winmd
A.B.Product.Client.Common.winmd
```

The public types must also be defined in the WinMD file with the longest prefix that matches the namespace.  So, if you have both **A.winmd** and **A.B.winmd**, the type `A.B.MyClass` must be defined in **A.B.winmd**.

So, why does your code work at runtime but not in the designer?  The naming rules for public types only apply to types defined in Windows Runtime components (for C++, DLL files), not for applications (EXEs).

However, to be able to instantiate your user-defined types (including `LayoutAwarePage`), the designer will load your project's EXE as a DLL, so the naming rules must be followed.

Comment: I also find (e.g. when moving a view model class to a different namespace) I have to close the designer window, build, and re-open the window for the component to be successfully reloaded by the designer.

Comment: @cflint07:  Closing and reopening the designer should not be required; it should reload automatically right after the build completes.  If that is not happening, please consider opening a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar bug, but then I closed VS, deleted the .suo, and reloaded the project and everything worked just fine.

Comment: The problem with doing this is that the software might not pass the store certification process. So this is a temporary solution only.

Comment: I see, I think I will just need to regenerate the .suo file. :)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. Then I found an article (http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/discussions/399736) that suggested 'unblocking' the DLL - mine were blocked, but unblocking them had no effect. Finally fixed the problem by deleting the suo and unblocking the DLL.