# C#/XAML Compile Error - Various Errors (The name "LayoutAwarePage" does not exist")

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

**EDIT**:

**Here are the pastebins for the code:**

[BasicPage1.xaml.cs](http://pastebin.com/s5akShjK)

[BasicPage1.xaml](http://pastebin.com/ZTmzxq78)

[LayoutAwarePage.cs](http://pastebin.com/DVwFEPKR)

**EDIT 2**

I have added a MS Connect ticket here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771648/c-xaml-compile-error-various-errors-the-name-layoutawarepage-does-not-exist#tabs

Right a head scratcher which I'm hoping others have experienced and know how to resolved as I'm a little disheartened by the whole affair.

**The Problem**

I have been working on a Windows Store App using C#/XAML to learn the ropes. After hours spent learning I decided to start my own App, which is fine. The issue is, after adding a few Views etc, I started getting the following error within my XAML files (All of them):

> Error 5   The name "LayoutAwarePage" does not exist in the namespace
>   "using:Accountable.Common".   G:\Coding Projects\Visual Studio
>   2012\SAVED\Accountable\Accountable\BasicPage1.xaml    1   1   Accountable

Which is strange because the **Accountable.Common** is declared within the XAML file:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="Accountable.BasicPage1"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Accountable"
xmlns:common="using:Accountable.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

So i read [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762100/xaml-designer-doesnt-work#tabs) that closing the XAML files down and closing **Visual Studio 2012** and re-opening, plus Building, resolves this issue. It didnt. It now causes the following errors within the Common files created when you first create new templates:

> Error 1   'Accountable.Common.BooleanNegationConverter' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object, System.Type,
>   object, string)'  G:\Coding Projects\Visual Studio
>   2012\SAVED\Accountable\Accountable\Common\BooleanNegationConverter.cs 9   25  Accountable
>
> Error 2   'Accountable.Common.BooleanNegationConverter' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type,
>   object, string)'  G:\Coding Projects\Visual Studio
>   2012\SAVED\Accountable\Accountable\Common\BooleanNegationConverter.cs 9   25  Accountable
>
> Error 3   'Accountable.Common.BooleanToVisibilityConverter' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object, System.Type,
>   object, string)'  G:\Coding Projects\Visual Studio
>   2012\SAVED\Accountable\Accountable\Common\BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs 20  25  Accountable
>
> Error 4   'Accountable.Common.BooleanToVisibilityConverter' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type,
>   object, string)'  G:\Coding Projects\Visual Studio
>   2012\SAVED\Accountable\Accountable\Common\BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs 20  25  Accountable

I haven't changed **BooleanNegationConverter.cs** or **BooleanToVisibility.cs**. What have i done to try and resolved the issue:

1. [Investigated other SO Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401440/layoutawarepage-does-not-exist-in-namespace-vs2012-bug), to no avail
2. Deleted the Solution SUO File with no luck
3. Removed my XAML Files, Classes (Models and ViewModels) and deleted Common Classes and created a new Basic Page. This causes the Project to load the classes again. The same problem.
4. Removed the reference to **Syncfusion Controls for WinRT XAML** which i used for custom DatePicker controls. Still the same issue.
5. Repaired Visual Studio 2012 - Nothing happened still the same problems.

I'm completely at a loss. I have created a new Project and the problem doesn't exist. I dont really want to start my Project again!

FYI - LayoutPageAware.cs is included in the Project:

[image]

Comment: Did you change namespace names or class names? Also, make sure that your xaml pages have correct Build Action = "Page" (Properties Window)

Comment: @surfen:Thanks for the response. Nope hadnt changed the code.I also deleted the code in the Common Folder and created a new Basic Page which re-creates the code. Unfortunately that didnt work. In addition build action is set to Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `LayoutAwarePage` is defined in the Common folder, and is automatically generated the first time you create a **Basic Page**

- Right Click on your prject
- Click Add
- Click "New Item"
- click "Basic Page"
- click add.

You might get a dialog saying

**"This addition depends on files that are missing from your project. Without these files you must resolve dependencies on the Common namespace manually.  Add the missing files automatically?"**

click yes

and then try building again

Comment: Hey Sam, thats the weird thing, LayoutAwarePage.cs is inlcuded in Common. Edited the post to include the Image.

Comment: I will pastepin it for you, bare with me :)

Comment: @garfbradaz can you also verify the namespace that your `LayoutAwarePage` class is declared under?

Comment: @garfbradaz try this:  copy your application's directory.  and then open the copy in visual studio.   Then delete the contents of the copy's `common` folder, add a new basic page, and then **build**(whether or not you see errors before you build), and see if it builds successfully.

Comment: Thanks matey. Unfortunately BasicPage2.xaml still has the same errors.

Comment: I did, exactly the same errors for BasicPage2.xaml as mentioned above. This one is a bugger! :P

Comment: @garfbradaz, will then, since a new project worked for you, I'd just copy/paste the important parts of your regular page to the new project and work with that

Comment: I think i will give that ago. Bloody annoying tho! Thanks for looking though appreciated.