# XAML Cannot locate LayoutAwarePage

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Windows Metro App, I created a Grid App and have added a whole bunch of forms and controls and pages,changed namespaces. Now I'm getting a XAML error saying it cannot locate `Common:LayoutAwarePage`.

I have looked at this article : [XAML cannot find reference in local namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004810/xaml-cannot-find-reference-in-local-namespace). However when looking through my application I cannot find any winmd files other than those for `Bing.Maps`

I created the project in Win 8 RP and vs 2012 RC, but have since upgraded the RTM versions of both . I even created a blank grid app and built it and there was no winmd file. Is there something I'm doing wrong and how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more informations about the `Common` namespace definition (I assume in XAML)? Sounds like it is not the right one

Comment: Hi Barry, did you have any luck solving this?