# How do I change the $(RootNamespace) macro in a WP8 C++ Component in VS 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I am trying to change the $(RootNamespace) of a WP8 runtime component to solve the same problem that this question is trying to solve: [Changing namespace name of C++ component in Windows Phone causes exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312941/changing-namespace-name-of-c-component-in-windows-phone-causes-exception)

However, the location of the RootNamespace macro definition appears to have moved in VS 2012.

When I press alt-enter after selecting my C++ project, I see this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/q1KF0As.jpg]
Which is the same window that you see when you right click > properties and as I understand, this shouldn't be the case. Either they changed the location of this mysterious property in VS 2012 or something is wrong with me.

I've bashed my head against this for some time now, so I would really appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I worked around this original issue by removing the $(RootNamespace) macro from the winmd filename and manually entering in the real root namespace. However, I'll leave the question open since my fix completely skirts around the original issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you, trying to follow the same instructions from the thread you referenced. That thread refers to the Properties Window (Ctrl+W,P), not the Property Pages (Shift+F4). Commonly confused. In the Properties Window you can set the value for Root Namespace.

[image]