# WP Runtime Component - Type load exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

## What works > Library setup

I have a Windows Phone 8 solution with 2 projects:

- "Hello", a simple library project -> generates **Hello.dll**.
- "HelloNativeRT", a WP Runtime Component with C++ files -> generates **HelloNativeRT.dll** and **HelloNativeRT.winmd**

In this solution, the "Hello" library references the WP Runtime Component, so calls like...

```
HelloNativeRT.SampleNamespace test = new HelloNativeRT.SampleNamespace();
```

...work fine in this library project.

## What doesn't work > WP8 app setup

However, **I want to use these two libraries in a Windows Phone 8 app**, but **without adding references to the projects**, since I need to ship the compiled libraries to clients.

- I referenced the **Hello.dll** file in the project, as well as the **HelloNativeRT.winmd** file.
- When I launch the application in debug mode, and goes to the line  `HelloNativeRT.SampleNamespace test = new HelloNative...` it crashes and says "TypeLoadException", like it cannot load the native module.

I suppose I need to include the **HelloNativeRT.dll** file in a way or another, since I guess it contains the native (compiled) code, as the winmd file may only embed the C++/CX code.

> > **How should I setup my project to include this DLL?**

I tried to put it at the root of the WP8 project, to reference it, to embed it... with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was quite simple in my case: the .winmd file and the .dll file generated from the WinRT Component must have **THE SAME NAME** (e.g: testRT.dll and testRT.winmd).

Then:

- Add the .winmd medata file as a reference in your project.
- Check that the .winmd / dll files are in the same folder to be correctly loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- Add a **reference** to your managed DLL file (the wrapper),
- Add a **reference** to your winmd metadata file (the WinPRT component),
- Add your native DLL library file as a **member of your project**, with build action to "**Content**" and "**Copy always**" selected.
- Add a **section to your manifest file**:

WPAppManifest:

```
<ActivatableClasses>
    <InProcessServer>
        <Path>external_component.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="external_component.MyComponent" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
</ActivatableClasses>
```

This last point is the one that is auto-magically done by Visual Studio when you reference a WinPRT project from a WP8 project ;-) I suppose not a lot of people are referencing native libs manually, since the documentation on that point is very sparse. The only link where I saw the solution mentionned was [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/2aa803b2-1d6b-43ae-af2d-ada54a349c72/wp8-how-to-use-a-native-component-in-a-separate-dll)...