# Exception only in one PC, in others work fine

Tags: c#, exception, windows-store-apps

I have an exception only in one PC, in others all work fine, anyone know wher it is comming from?

> dditional information: Requested Windows Runtime type
>   'Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture' is not registered.

This exception is showing only in modern style apps (windows strore app) in windows 8.1. In WPF or Windows Form apps camera works fine. Code is fine, because in other pc work great:) i install system one more time, but the exception still showing up.

Comment: whats installed on the other computers that isn't installed on the one causing the problems? Could a service be disabled?

Comment: Same OS, same Visual Studio. Other stuff inside in bought examples OS was just installed. I already tried USB cam device, which work on others. Still nothing.

Comment: can you take a look at this and see if it is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228964/wp-runtime-component-type-load-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Microsoft's Windows Universal Samples (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cs/AudioCapturePermissions.cs#L35) shows following piece of code

```
try
{
    // Request access to the microphone only, to limit the number of capabilities we need
    // to request in the package manifest.
    MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
    settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
    settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Speech;
    MediaCapture capture = new MediaCapture();

    await capture.InitializeAsync(settings);
}
catch (TypeLoadException)
{
    // On SKUs without media player (eg, the N SKUs), we may not have access to the Windows.Media.Capture
    // namespace unless the media player pack is installed. Handle this gracefully.
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Media player components are unavailable.");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    return false;
}
```

So you have to install "Media player components".

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue with Windows 10. I had installed the N edition, but it looks like since it is missing Media Player, the classes related to MediaCapture are also missing.
As Hans Passant mentioned, the MediaCapture class was not registered in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\ActivatableClassId.

I reinstalled Window 10 (not the N edition) and now the class is registered.