# Requested Windows Runtime type 'PrintService.PDFPrinting' is not registered

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to develop a brokered WinRT silent PDF printing service for a UWP application using [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/527286e4-b06a-4234-adde-d313c9c3c23e).

I have followed all the steps on how to create a brokered WinRT component. But when I call the service on the UWP app, I get the below error:

> Requested Windows Runtime type 'PrintService.PDFPrinting' is not
>   registered.

My brokered component class:

```
public sealed class PDFPrinting
{
    public Boolean PrintPDFs(string pdfFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

            //Define location of adobe reader/command line
            //switches to launch adobe in "print" mode
            proc.StartInfo.FileName =
              @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", pdfFileName);
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            proc.Start();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            if (proc.HasExited == false)
            {
                proc.WaitForExit(10000);
            }

            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            proc.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How I call it:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\...\mydocument.pdf";
var service = new PrintService.PDFPrinting();
service.PrintPDFs(path);
```

My extenssion:

```
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
<InProcessServer>
  <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>
  <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PrintService.PDFPrinting" ThreadingModel="MTA">
    <ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" Value="C:\Development\MyApp" />
  </ActivatableClass>
</InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

Comment: It is trying to tell you that PrintService.PDFPrinting does not appear to be part of your appx manifest.  Do ensure that the Extension element appears in your AppxManifest.xml file.

Comment: @HansPassant I checked it. It's there in the AppxManifest.xml file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20637241/17034

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the reference, but that is different from what I'm doing. But I did find the solution, the value path in my extension was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, my value path in the UWP Package.appxmanifest extension was wrong.

I referenced:

```
<ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" Value="C:\Development\MyApp" />
```

Instead of:

```
<ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" Value="C:\Development\MyApp\MyApp\Debug" />
```

Which is where all associated support files and the proxy/stub dll are located.
Details found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps)

Comment: @FrageDeFaine Is it possible with VS2017 ?