# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error when Calling WinRT Component in WP 8 (C#)

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I have loaded all the DLLs in the project and my code breaks when I want from the WP8 App to create an object that is defined in my WinRT component (that calls other native libraries).

amy I missing something imporant ?

Thanks

Comment: What file's not found? What code are you using? What error? What stack trace?

Comment: That is one of my problem, how can i figure out which DLL is not loading ? if I can figure that out then i can fix the error

Comment: Runtime error or compile-time error?

Answer (score 1):

No definitive answer, just some ideas to try if you haven't already.

Have you got any warnings from the build? In particular you need to watch that the C++/CX namespace and .winmd file name are compatible (see [this SO question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312941/changing-namespace-name-of-c-component-in-windows-phone-causes-exception)).

Have you tried using the Native Debugger?

- If so, does it even get to the  constructor of your ref class object?
- Does the text in the Output Window give you any clues as to what is missing?

Open up your .XAP file from the build directory using any ZIP packaging tool (you could for example rename it to .zip and use Windows Explorer) - are all the DLLs you expect packaged up correctly?

Comment: interesting, when Deploying in native mode I get `First-chance exception at 0x770B1247 (KERNELBASE.DLL) in TaskHost.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131534, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x70EB0000)` .... any idea what that means btw thanks for the tips, had tried everything else except Native :P